# Call Variable with a equal named parameter

Tags: jquery, variables, parameters, redirect

I wanted to create a script for redirection on a website, but currently without much success :D

My idea was to create some arrays like so:

```
var google = [
    Google Searching,
    http://www.google.com/
]

var amazon = [
    Amazon Shopping
    http://www.amazon.com/
]
```

Furthermore I wanted to write a function which creates a modal box with some information and the redirection. No Problem, but I don’t know how to call this arrays with a parameter.

For example:

```
gotoWebsite(google);

function gotoWebsite (website){
    //search array "google" with the paramter
    alert (google[0]);
    alert (google[1]);
}
```

This example should alert `Google Searching` and `http://www.google.com/`

**Question:** How can I call the array with the equal named parameter?

Comment: Do yo want to pass `"Google"` (or any other string) to `gotoWebsite()` then alert those information?

Comment: Correct. Later, i want to call the function `gotoWebsite()` in HTML. The parameter should always call the variable with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question, but here's what to do. First, your quotes `„` and `“` could be problematic as seen in your post, use `"` (double quotes) or `'` (single quotes).

Now for solving your problem. You need to create a container `object()`, let it be `websites` as below

```
var websites = {};
```

Then place your websites objects* inside `websites` object like

```
var websites = { 
    google: { 
        name: "Google", 
        url: "https://www.google.com"
    }, 
    amazon: { 
        name: "Amazon", 
        url: "https://www.amazon.com"
    }
    /* More objectes */
}
```

Now we have an object that we can using `key`, but we need to wrap inside of a function. You can move `websites` object to `gotoWebsite()` scope if you have problems with it such as

> websites is undefined

```
function gotoWebsite(website){

    console.log(websites[website]['name']); // Google
    console.log(websites[website]['url']); // http://www.google.com

    // OR get current key for passed parameter and assign to a variable 

    var website =  websites[website];
    console.log(website['name']); // Google
    console.log(website['url']); // http://www.google.com


}
```

Usage:

```
gotoWebsite('google');
// Google
// http://www.google.com
```

Here's a live example, track of [`Web Console`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) to see the output

```js
var websites = { 
    google: { name: "Google", url: "https://www.google.com" }, 
    amazon: { name: "Amazon", url: "https://www.amazon.com" }
}

function gotoWebsite(website){

    var website = websites[website];
    console.log(website['name']);
    console.log(website['url']);
        
}
gotoWebsite('google');
gotoWebsite('amazon');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to dynamically define websites that can be linked, I suggest starting with an array, and a function to add elements to that array:

```
var websites = [];

function newWebsite(name,title,url) {
    websites[name] = [ title, url ];
}
```

Then the goto function should then have a clause to handle trying to link a site that hasn't been defined yet:

```
function gotoWebsite (website){
    var site = websites[website];
    if (site === "array") {
        alert (site[0]);
        alert (site[1]);
    } else {
        alert ("unknown website: " + website);
    }
}
```

sites can be registered from any script with access to the function:

```
newWebsite("google","Google Searching","http://www.google.com/");
newWebsite("amazon","Amazon Shopping","http://www.amazon.com/");
```

and then the goto function can get the sites by name

```
gotoWebsite("google");
```